# Signing an XML file (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-signature

I am facing an issue while trying to sign an XML file to make a soap request.
Here is the function I am using to get the signature in a variable:

```
private function signXml() {

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($this->xml);

    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'SignedInfo') as $elm) {
        $SignedInfo =  $elm->c14n(); 

        $key = openssl_pkey_get_private ( file_get_contents($this->lc_key) , $this->lc_Password); //file_get_contents($this->key);

        if ( openssl_sign($SignedInfo, $crypt, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1) ) {
            $this->data['SignatureValue'] = base64_encode($crypt);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('XML signature failed !');
        }
    }
}
```

When I use SoapUI to generate the signature, the request is successfully processed by the server. But when I use my php script I get a different signature, though the digestValues is the same and the server rises an Internal Error.

This are the standards I should use:

Key Identifiert Type => Binary Security Token

Signature Algorithm => http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

Signature Canonicalization => http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

Digest Algorithm => sha1

Signed Message Part => Body

Comment: What error is the server raising? And please state a question: what, exactly, do you want people to provide you?

Comment: "bad signature or with the wrong algorithm". I am looking for a way to generate the same signature than soapUI. I don't know if there is another way to sign an XML.

Comment: @JilanA. did you find a solution?

Comment: no sorry, a friend of mine developed a C# solution and it worked ....